# Problems in signing in to Hotmail

Tags: outlook.com

Seem that someone tried to sign in to my email in `live.com` with a wrong password too many times. So I am locked out right now. I can reset my password just with security question, but that lovely guy has caused that to be lock also, with entering a wrong answer too many times. So it is temporarily unavailable too. I have filled the costumer support form, many times, but there is no answer from them.

Now my questions are:

1. How long the security question is unavailable? So far it has been unavailable for three days after the problem.
2. Is there another solution for this problem?
3. If I try to enter the answer to the question while it is unavailable, can that extend the time I am locked out?

Answer (score 2):

It may time out within a day, but if not in cases like these, you may need to recover the account. What that means is either customer support or web form will take you through a series of questions about the account that only you could know, like creation date (don't worry, they realize that it won't be down to the specific day), or maybe someone you e-mailed a long time ago regularly, and other such things about the account that are not accessible from within the account.

Follow the steps here:

http://www.windowslivehelp.com/solution.aspx?solutionid=bf5d34bf-db28-44ca-ac9a-93838d81b2d6